# Why are images on my WordPress website not displaying on mobile phone

Tags: html, wordpress, breakpoints

Hello my website with link herehttp://box5666.temp.domains/~thelebd4/nsocompany/peermont/

The images display on desktop but not on a mobile phone, I have tried playing with the settings but can't seem to get it.

Please note is a WordPress website thank you.

Comment: This is a HTML issue. You need to change the grid to show on smaller breakpoints. You can test using your browser dev tools

Comment: 3Can you help please i do not really understand

Comment: i need your help please